# I have an anonymous function without parentheses, how does this work?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

New to javascript,but i know that form

```
<script>(function(){ somecode })();</script>
```

will immediately run somecode when it be interpreted.But when i was reading a html5 game source code,I encountered some code which form like this:

```
<script>(function(){})</script>
```

There is no parentheses attached.So what does it mean?

source code:https://github.com/oxyflour/STGame
and the index.html has code form like below:

```
<script>(function(){})</script>
```

Comment: It looks useless to me. I don't see any other references to the numerous script tag IDs in the repository either.

Comment: It just evaluates and returns. So as written it does nothing. Maybe it was called in the past and the author preferred this over commenting away or deleting the code. If it was a named function: `(function someName(RES){})`, it would prevent someName from becoming a global, compared to `function someName(RES){}`, which would make a global.

Comment: The first one is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), i.e. an anonymous function that is called immediately after its definition and not stored anywhere (not able to call it again). The second one is explained by @shrys in [their answer](/a/57110417/4265352) but it is not recommended for several reasons (the way it is used is not standard and it is hidden in a different script; using `eval` is slow and dangerous).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer the [game.js](https://github.com/oxyflour/STGame/blob/be4009e89c938cc6db7fb1accb293df471205a7d/js/game.js#L699) file, they are using it as nodes that don't do anything(@Shilly) and accessing them with `id` in the script tag. I don't know what is being done with the `d` object but certainly it is being called somewhere, look how they're using the `innerHTML`

```js
else if (v.tagName == 'SCRIPT' && $attr(v, 'type') == 'text/html') {
  d[v.id] = v.innerHTML;
} else if (v.tagName == 'SCRIPT') {
  d[v.id] = eval(v.innerHTML)(_t);
}
```

---

An example of what's being done:

```js
eval(document.getElementById('myscript').innerHTML)('test');
```

```html
<script id="myscript">
(function(a) {
  a ? console.log(a) : console.log('some string')
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [`game.js` source](https://github.com/oxyflour/STGame/blob/master/js/game.js#L702) I found this piece of code after a quick scan:

```
// ... line 702
else if (v.tagName == 'SCRIPT') {
  d[v.id] = eval(v.innerHTML)(_t);
}
// ...
```

So it's getting the innerHTML of the `<script/>` tag and executing it via `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this does nothing. It only evaluates and returns, so no call or anything.

The `(function(){})()` is called an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) - Immediately Invoked Function Expression). This, however, is an IIFE without the last parentheses (`()` at the end), which means it will not be called right after its definition.

Therefore, the purpose of this code might be either to keep for later use or maybe the person writing it forgot to call it or something similar. It's not a pattern that is actually used anywhere that I have seen.